# Split dynamic list into sublist based on special character in python

Tags: python

I have one basic question in python where i am trying to find solution for a long time but i am unable to get correct output.

```
textvalues=[['1 of 2 DOCUMENTS', 'The New York Times', 'March 17, 2016 Thursday\xa0\xa0Late Edition - Final', 'Paid Notice: Deaths THORNTON, ROBERT', 'SECTION: Section A; Column 0; Classified; Pg. 19', 'LENGTH: 176 words', 'LOAD-DATE: March 17, 2016', 'Copyright 2016 The New York Times Company', '', '2 of 2 DOCUMENTS', 'The New York Times', 'March 16, 2016 Wednesday\xa0\xa0Late Edition - Final', 'Paid Notice: Deaths THORNTON, ROBERT', 'SECTION: Section B; Column 0; Classified; Pg. 16', 'LENGTH: 176 words', 'LOAD-DATE: March 16, 2016', 'Copyright 2016 The New York Times Company']]
```

Here i need to split the above list into sublist based on '' special character. The above list is sample list and main list is dynamic where the length of the list may differ. In any case, the list  need to be separated by '' character.

Solution that i have tried:

```
MainText = str(textvalues)
split_index = MainText.index( '',)
l2 = MainText[:split_index]
print(l2)
```

Expected solution:

```
[['1 of 2 DOCUMENTS', 'The New York Times', 'March 17, 2016 Thursday\xa0\xa0Late Edition - Final', 'Paid Notice: Deaths THORNTON, ROBERT', 'SECTION: Section A; Column 0; Classified; Pg. 19', 'LENGTH: 176 words', 'LOAD-DATE: March 17, 2016', 'Copyright 2016 The New York Times Company'] ,['2 of 2 DOCUMENTS', 'The New York Times', 'March 16, 2016 Wednesday\xa0\xa0Late Edition - Final', 'Paid Notice: Deaths THORNTON, ROBERT', 'SECTION: Section B; Column 0; Classified; Pg. 16', 'LENGTH: 176 words', 'LOAD-DATE: March 16, 2016', 'Copyright 2016 The New York Times Company']]
```

Please help me to resolve the issue. Thanks

Comment: Check Right leg's solution. It works with a little modification. see my code in the comment to his answer.

Comment: Check my solution if it works for you.

Answer (score 1):

```
import itertools

textvalues=[['1 of 2 DOCUMENTS', 'The New York Times', 'March 17, 2016 Thursday\xa0\xa0Late Edition - Final', 'Paid Notice: Deaths THORNTON, ROBERT', 'SECTION: Section A; Column 0; Classified; Pg. 19', 'LENGTH: 176 words', 'LOAD-DATE: March 17, 2016', 'Copyright 2016 The New York Times Company', '', '2 of 2 DOCUMENTS', 'The New York Times', 'March 16, 2016 Wednesday\xa0\xa0Late Edition - Final', 'Paid Notice: Deaths THORNTON, ROBERT', 'SECTION: Section B; Column 0; Classified; Pg. 16', 'LENGTH: 176 words', 'LOAD-DATE: March 16, 2016', 'Copyright 2016 The New York Times Company']]
groups = []
for a,b in itertools.groupby(textvalues[0], lambda x: x is not ''):
    if a:
        groups.append(list(b))
print groups
```

Output:

```
[['1 of 2 DOCUMENTS', 'The New York Times', 'March 17, 2016 Thursday\xa0\xa0Late Edition - Final', 'Paid Notice: Deaths THORNTON, ROBERT', 'SECTION: Section A; Column 0; Classified; Pg. 19', 'LENGTH: 176 words', 'LOAD-DATE: March 17, 2016', 'Copyright 2016 The New York Times Company'], ['2 of 2 DOCUMENTS', 'The New York Times', 'March 16, 2016 Wednesday\xa0\xa0Late Edition - Final', 'Paid Notice: Deaths THORNTON, ROBERT', 'SECTION: Section B; Column 0; Classified; Pg. 16', 'LENGTH: 176 words', 'LOAD-DATE: March 16, 2016', 'Copyright 2016 The New York Times Company']]
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you can loop over the content, store the substrings in a buffer, and dump the buffer to the main list when coming across the `''` separator:

```
result = list()
line = list()
for element in textvalues[0]:
    if element != '':
        line.append(element)
    else:
        result.append(line)
        line = list()
```

Comment: A fix to your solution. Check this and edit your answer. `textvalues=[[' asd', '', ' asd d ', '', 'c as  d', '', 'asd f', '', 'lskd']]
result = []
line = []
for element in textvalues[0]:
    if element != '':
        line.append(element)
    else:
        result.append(line)
        line = []
else:
    result.append(line)

print result`

Comment: Output of the above code: `[[' asd'], [' asd d '], ['c as  d'], ['asd f'], ['lskd']]`

Comment: Sorry about the first answer, I wrote it in a hurry, and saw it didn't work after testing it. I edited right away, so the very first code I posted did not work, but the edit I made before the comments corrected it. I tested it, and it works.

Comment: @Mho 1 `else` if for the `for loop` and 1 `else` for `if` condtion. Indent it properly. It will work. Also check my solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
textvalues=[['1 of 2 DOCUMENTS', 'The New York Times', 'March 17, 2016 Thursday\xa0\xa0Late Edition - Final', 'Paid Notice: Deaths THORNTON, ROBERT', 'SECTION: Section A; Column 0; Classified; Pg. 19', 'LENGTH: 176 words', 'LOAD-DATE: March 17, 2016', 'Copyright 2016 The New York Times Company', '', '2 of 2 DOCUMENTS', 'The New York Times', 'March 16, 2016 Wednesday\xa0\xa0Late Edition - Final', 'Paid Notice: Deaths THORNTON, ROBERT', 'SECTION: Section B; Column 0; Classified; Pg. 16', 'LENGTH: 176 words', 'LOAD-DATE: March 16, 2016', 'Copyright 2016 The New York Times Company']]

textvalues2 = []

for i in ','.join(i for i in textvalues[0]).split(',,') :
    textvalues2.append( i.split(',') )
```